# Syntax highlighting in emacs with perl .t files

Tags: perl, unit-testing, emacs

I am using GNU Emacs 24.2.1 to write some perl code. Syntax highlighting works well for files with extension `.pl` and `.pm`,  but unfortunately not for perl unit tests (`.t` extension),

Is there a simple way to automatically turn on perl syntax highlighting whenever I open a `.t` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Popular question. I've answered a similar one a few days back: [Emacs: How to use a major mode for non-standard file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661413/emacs-how-to-use-a-major-mode-for-non-standard-file-extension).

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.t\\'" . perl-mode))
```

Comment: This will also apply to `foo.tex` and `bar.txt` and `baz.tar.gz`.  You want to use `"\\.t\\'"` to avoid this problem.